# script to ssh into hardware

Tags: ssh, switch-statement

There is a switch which I would like to automate. The script would ssh into the switch with proper credentials (admin/admin) and configure it and log out. It would then do X things. Then  it would login again and configure it differently to do Y things. X and Y are simple and should not pose any problems whatsoever.

Kindly help me here.

Comment: Which bit do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.debianadmin.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-password-authentication.html) is a tool which will allow you to do what I think you want to do.

It allows you to give the password to ssh via command-line instead of interactively.